# ASP.NET Custom cache provider not working with data cache api

Tags: asp.net, caching, memcached

I've implemented the custom cache provider for memcached using Enyim.Caching and Enyim.Caching.Web. The problem is its working fine when I use it from Outputcache directive on page but its not working when I try using the cache data api like this

```
Page.Cache["myKey"] = "some string value";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out myself that custom cache provider only works for Output cache and not for Data cache.